# List and details in the same page without action of the user and using RaW SQL

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i'm newbie from django. I woould like to implement this logic . For each author in the table Author , get in the same page all the books written from the author , directly without click in other page for detail view. I want this using  raw sql , because the query that i use are very complex, this is just an exaple for you for support your help.

I've this custom def in view.py

```
def my_custom_sql(Id):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('''select Id, Author from 
                        AuthorTable as PG
                        left join BooksTable TS on 
                        TS.Author =PG.Author 
                         WHERE PG.Id= %s ''', [Id])
        row = cursor. cursor.fetchall() 
    return row

def preview(request):
    AllItem  = Author.objects.all()
 
    _list = list(AllItem)
    for item in _list:
        Id=item.Id
        detail=my_custom_sql(Id)

    context = {
        'AllItem': AllItem,
        'detail': detail,
    }
    print(context)
    return render(request, 'home/home.html', context)
```

If i get the `print(context)` output in the  terminal, i've the wrong data

```
{'AllItem': <QuerySet [<Author: AAA1>, <Author: AAA2>]>, 'detail': [(2,  'AAA2', 'Book2'), (2, 'AAA2', 'Book3')]}
```

i get just the books of Author AAA2 and are missing the books of Author AAA1 ( in the table of course are there).

Where i wrong?, For similar purpose is the correct way to get what i want?
Thans all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing neither a django nor a SQL problem. You got a python problem.

```py
for item in _list:
    Id=item.Id
    detail=my_custom_sql(Id)
```

With every iteration you do in this loop, the variables `Id` and `detail` get overwritten. Thus even with a queryset of 100 authors you would just end up with the books of the last one.

Change it to something like this:

```py
def preview(request):
    AllItem  = Author.objects.all()
 
    _list = list(AllItem)
    author_details = []
    for item in _list:
        Id=item.Id
        detail=my_custom_sql(Id)
        author_details.append(detail)

    context = {
        'AllItem': AllItem,
        'detail': author_details,
    }
    print(context)
    return render(request, 'home/home.html', context)
```

Append the the detail information which you retrieved via that raw sql command to a persistent list (here called `author_details`).

This should give you two lists: 
`AllItem` --> with the queryset of all authors 
`detail` --> with the books for each author.

If it is easier you could also return it as a zipped thingy

```py
context['author_and_books'] = zip(AllItem, author_details)
```

And in your template do like:

```html
{% for author, books in author_and_books %}
<span>First the author: {{ author }}</span>
<table>
{% for book in books %}
<tr><td>{{ book }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}  
</table>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yes, of course ... sorry for the questioin maybe stupid...but i'm bit confuse sometime and often i place directy blame to django !  Tanks for your help!!!

Comment: In  your opinion is this a good approch? Exist a better alternative?

Comment: You could avoid the for loop doing a "normal" django lookup. But since this is just an example for a more complex sql query, it is not on my to judge if there is a better way. You can do very advanced stuff via the django lookups. I'd be surprised if raw sql is really needed. Maybe this gets you on track: [Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)